# SQL - Count Results of 2 Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table which contains ID's and UserId's.

```
ID           UserID
1111         11
1111         300
1111         51
1122         11
1122         22
1122         3333
1122         45
```

I'm trying to count the distinct number of 'IDs' so that I get a total, but I also need to get a total of ID's that have also seen the that particular ID as well... To get the ID's, I've had to perform a subquery within another table to get ID's, I then pass this into the main query... Now I just want the results to be displayed as follows.

So I get a Total No for ID and a Total Number for Users ID - Also would like to add another column to get average as well for each ID

```
TotalID    Total_UserID   Average
2          7              3.5
```

If Possible I would also like to get an average as well, but not sure how to calculate that. So I would need to count all the 'UserID's for an ID add them altogether and then find the AVG. (Any Advice on that caluclation would be appreciated.)

Current Query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(a.ID)
,COUNT(b.UserID)
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON someID = someID
WHERE a.ID IN ( SELECT ID FROM c WHERE GROUPID = 9999)
GROUP BY a.ID
```

Which then Lists all the IDs and COUNT's all the USERID.. I would like a total of both columns. I've tried warpping the query in a

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
```

but this only counts the ID's which is great, but how do I count the USERID column as well

Comment: ' I also need to get a total of ID's that have also seen the that particular ID' you are never showing any particular ID - are you just wanting to know how many distinct ID there are any how many UserId there are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.ID), COUNT(b.UserID),
       COUNT(b.UserID) * 1.0 / COUNT(DISTINCT a.ID)
FROM a INNER JOIN
     b
     ON someID = someID
WHERE a.ID IN ( SELECT ID FROM c WHERE GROUPID = 9999);
```

Note:  `DISTINCT` is *not* a function.  It applies to the whole row, so it is misleading to put an expression in parentheses after it.

Also, the `GROUP BY` is unnecessary.

The `1.0` is because SQL Server does integer arithmetic and this is a simple way to convert a number to a decimal form.

Comment: Fixed my issues, Looks like I wasn't that far off from getting the syntax right.. Thanks. Now I need to link all of my queries together.

Comment: One last question - Is it possible to round the result of the AVERAGE to a whole number.

Comment: @Boardman411 . . . That is definitely not the question you asked, but you can use `round()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.ID) ...
```

to count all distinct values

Read details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want this:

```
select TotalID,
    Total_UserID,
    sum(Total_UserID+TotalID) as Total,
    Total_UserID/TotalID as Average
from (
    SELECT (DISTINCT a.ID) as TotalID
    ,COUNT(b.UserID) as Total_UserID
    FROM a
    INNER JOIN b ON someID = someID
    WHERE a.ID IN ( SELECT ID FROM c WHERE GROUPID = 9999)
) x
```